# Programmatically clicking 'Cancel' on 'Edit Properties' window

Tags: development, document-library

After a document is uploaded, the 'Edit Properties' window is displayed.

Due to restrictions with integration with other applications, the 'Edit Properties' window must be displayed, but I need to immediately close it without any user input.

I'm using C# to run some workflows immediately after a document is uploaded, so it will show that the SharePoint system has made changes, so if a user clicks 'Save' on that 'Edit Properties' window, it will throw an error.

Could someone point me in the right direction of where to start? Is there a way to just click the 'Cancel' button with code?

**Edit:** Per advice below, I have tried to add a javascript snippet (I confused jquery with javascript...) [window.location.href = "http://test.com";] but it redirects every time a user navigates to the Edit Properties window. My intention was only for it to close the window upon upload. Users should be able to access it otherwise. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom EditForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer. This EditForm will have some javascript behind it that can "Click" the Cancel button with jquery using `.click()`, or have the user redirected to a page using `window.location.href`

Comment: and without jQuery: ``document.querySelector( [SELECTOR] ).click()``

Comment: yes! I do not like using jquery if I don't have to.

Comment: Hi Danny, Mike - Thank you for your replies! I have looked into it an added that snippet of code, but it closes the window every time I open it (I guess that is to be expected, though). I was hoping to only close it that one time on document upload. Is there a different place (workflow code, EditForm.aspx) that would be a better candidate?

Comment: You could add a clause or something that indicates that if the `document.referrer === <List Upload Form URL>` THEN redirect or close.

Comment: Hi, Mike! Thank you for your patience with my question. I have added the following code: 

<script language="javascript" type ="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer === 'http://[URL]/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=[GUID]' ) {
window.location.href = "http://[URL].com";
}
</script>

But I get an error about the site being disposed immaturely. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: try adding it like this between the script tags: `(function() { 
   if (document.referrer === 'http://[URL]/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=[GUID]' ) { window.location.href = "http://[URL].com"; })()`

Comment: Ah, no dice. I think something with how the third party applications is conflicting with any script I put in. I think the Edit Properties page goes through several re-directs or something, if I look at the Network tab. I'll have to play around with it. But thank you for your patience and advice! :) I learned a lot.

Comment: If it works manually with one click, then maybe wrap the .click() in a setTimeout